# What is the integral of the 1-form field $x dy$ over the straight-line path from (2, 0) to (0, 3).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Unsure of how I should approach this... Should we parametrize the path first and then integrate?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Stokes’ theorem reduces the integral to something quite simple.